# Find value of angles in the following Trignometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, inverse, substitution

I was wondering what is the best and accurate way of finding the values of angles in the following equations.

1. $2\cos^2 x - \sin x = 0 $
2. $2\cos^2 x \sin x - 2 = 0 $

I tried to do it but I was hitting a dead end with every approach.
I thought it will be good to hear opinions.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Take $\sin{x}=t$.

The first gives $$2t^2+t-2=0$$ or $$t=\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{4}$$ or
$$x=(-1)^n\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{4}+\pi n,$$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$.

The second we can rewrite so:
$$\cos^2x\sin{x}=1,$$ which gives $$\sin{x}=\cos^2x=1,$$ which is impossible because $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1.$

Thus, the second equation has no real roots.

Answer (score 0):

the first equation we can write as
$$2(1-\sin^2(x))-\sin(x)=0$$
or
$$-2\sin(x)^2-\sin(x)+2=0$$ for $t=\sin(x)$ we get
$$-2t^2-t+2=0$$
and you can solve a quadratic equation.
in the second one $$2(1-\sin(x)^2)\sin(x)-2=0$$ or
$$-2\sin^3(x)+2\sin(x)-2=0$$
and dividing by $-2$ we get
$$\sin(x)^3-\sin(x)+1=0$$ with $t=\sin(x)$ we have
$$t^3-t+1=0$$